# How to transfer int variable from python to javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, mysql, google-maps

I am currently doing a project wherein latitudes and longitudes are stored in a MySQL database. I plan to use these coordinates to create an overlay on top of google maps. to do that I require the maximum and minimum latitude and longitude, signifying the area over which the overlay will be. I have already written a python program which determines all of these coordinates. However, the coordinates need to be in a js program with the google maps API. I wanted to know whether it would be possible for me to transfer these variables to javascript. If not what would be the easiest way for me to run an SQL query from javascript and store the results to an integer variable?

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all NEVER allow running SQL from JavaScript, its was too insecure and anybody can edit the query on the client side and fire any SQL query that way.

You can retrieve the longitude -latitude value from python script and before passing it to google maps API  in JavaScript and just to be 100% sure that they are float or int Values you can use `parseFloat()` or `parseInt()` .

Here us sample usage and results of parse float function.

**JS code**

```
var a = parseFloat("10") + "<br>";
var b = parseFloat("10.00") + "<br>";
var c = parseFloat("10.33") + "<br>";
var d = parseFloat("34 45 66") + "<br>";
var e = parseFloat(" 60 ") + "<br>";
var f = parseFloat("40 years") + "<br>";
var g = parseFloat("He was 40") + "<br>";
```

**Output**

```
10
10
10.33
34
60
40
NaN
```

On how to get values from python script you can refer to [this tutorail](http://kooneiform.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/python-and-ajax-for-beginners-with-webpy-and-jquery/)